# How could I render just the form from an autoform?

Tags: plone

I'm in the context of a BrowserView. I want to render a form inside the page.

```
class CommandeView(BrowserView):
    ...
    def render_myform(self):
        livraison_form = LivraisonForm(self.context, self.request)
        livraison_form.update()
        return livraison_form.render()

class ILivraisonForm(interface.Interface):
    livraison = schema.Choice(title=_(u"Mode de livraison"),
                          vocabulary=livraison_vocabulary)


class LivraisonForm(AutoExtensibleForm, form.EditForm):
    schema = ILivraisonForm

class LivraisonFormAdapter(object):
    component.adapts(ICommande)
    interface.implements(ILivraisonForm)
    def __init__(self, context):
        self.context = context
        self.livraison = self.context.livraison
```

I would like render_myform to render only the form but it return a HTML Plone page.

Any tips are welcomed.

Comment: Have you tried with a FormWrapper ? I'm not sure it works in the case of a browserview

Comment: The formwrapper is to create a page to display the form. I want the opposite: display a form inside an existing page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't checked this in-depth, but the form is probably wrapped by the plone `FormWrapper` class.

Look for a `.form` attribute on the `LivraisonForm` instance:

```
def render_myform(self):
    livraison_form = LivraisonForm(self.context, self.request).form
    livraison_form.update()
    return livraison_form.render()
```

It *may* be you need to add an additional interface to the request for this to work (the wrapper normally does this for you. I'm a little low on time right now, so you get this untested:

```
from plone.z3cform import z2

class CommandeView(BrowserView):
    def render_myform(self):
        z2.switch_on(self)  # Apply layer interface, set up locale, add `getURL` method
        livraison_form = LivraisonForm(self.context, self.request).form
        livraison_form.update()
        return livraison_form.render()
```

The Plone Knowledgebase uses this same setup to [show a form in a viewlet](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/using-z3c.form-forms-in-plone/creating-a-z3c.form-inside-a-viewlet/).